# Package dart lib into single javascript file to make lib available in websites

Tags: javascript, compilation, dart, dart2js

I wrote my first library in dart. Now I want to make use of it in a website. My idea was to compile all necessary dart code of my lib and its dependencies into one javascript file that has a useful "global" API. As I understand this I would also write this API in dart and compile it altogether to javascript but I fail to see how this is done. The https://www.dartlang.org/tools/dart2js/ wasn't particular helpful to me.

To give a simplified example: The library is a generic parser controlled by a grammar. A parse-tree is build from some input file and a grammar. Think of it like:

```
ParseTree parse(File input, File grammar);
```

So in the resulting javascript I want to have this available in some form so one could write e.g.

```
var tree = MyParserLib.parse("path/to/input.file", "my.gramamar.file");
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you build your entire app at once. Building distinct parts or libraries to JS and using the output in another app is not (yet?) well supported.

Comment: Say this API I talk about is my entire app. How would I do that than?

Comment: If this is an entire app, you execute `pub build` inside your apps directory and deploy the content of `your_package/build/web` (assuming your entry page was in `your_package/web`)